# With natural n and d a specific divisor of n, how many natural numbers are one greater than a number coprime to n and a multiple of d?

Tags: number-theory

Concerning the cardinality of
{ m | gcd(m-1,n)=1 and d|m },
can it be written as a function of n and d without a set where n and m are natural numbers and d is a specific divisor of n?

Comment: Your title and set notation don't match.  Your title would be $\{m|\gcd(m,n)=$ and $(m-1)|n\}$. Your set notation is saying if $n$ and $d$ divides $n$ (a specific $d$? Or there is a divisor?) this is the set  so that $n$ is rel. prime to the number and $d$ divides one more than the number.  Which one are you asking about.

Comment: The question is fixed.

Comment: If d and n/d are coprime, that would be $\varphi(n/d)$. Otherwise things get complicated.